How many shiva lingas can be kept at home?
What does the puranam say about keeping the number of shiva lingas at home? We traditionally have one shivalinga at the main room , on the deity altar along with maa Kali and other deity pictures , but for sadhana I am thinking bout buying a narmadeswar shivalinga . So can I keep it a my room separate from the deity room in my house . Thank you.
